# How to get product url with category key on home page

Tags: magento2, product, url

I want to get product url with category key in it on home page.

for example:

www.example.com/category/product.html

Thanks

Comment: Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" set to "Yes"

Comment: Thanks, but it is adding category url key on category page (products) not on home page

Comment: Please give more detail where u want exactly. Screenshot?

Comment: I have a new products slider on home page and i want to add url key of category(first category in which that product is found) in its link.

Comment: Product URL should be same throughout Website right? Only on homepage u want with Category? What is purpose?

Comment: yes, only on home page

Comment: What u want to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Its my client's requirement may be for SEO

Comment: Did you find any solution for this im looking for the same but unable to find 
Please let me know

Answer (score 3):

go to Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" set to "Yes"

[image]

After that Reindex using  **php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

Answer (score 3):

If you have a product collection, you will need to specify a category for each product in the collection.

If you are using a category collection the category from the collection will be used.

The product you are generating a URL for will need to know which category it should include in the url, which is why if you just load the product without mentioning a category, you will not return any category in the path even if you adjust the admin settings like others have recommended.

Some psuedo code to get you started:

```
// Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18300258/magento-getproducturl-does-not-include-category-path

$product->setCategoryId($categoryId)->getProductUrl();
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the below code today for a similar thing

```
public function __construct(
        ...   
             \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
                \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
                \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
        ...
            ) {
        ...
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        ...
    }

...
$categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    if (!$categoryIds) {
        return null;
    }
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryIds[0], $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    $this->registry->register('current_category',$category);
    $redirectionUrl =     $product->getProductUrl();
...
```

Comment: How to use above code ? Do I need to create custom module for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I did this by using following code

```
<?php $_objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); ?>
                        <?php     $cats = $_item->getCategoryIds();
                                if(count($cats) ){

                                    if($cats[0]==2){
                                        $firstCategoryId = $cats[1];
                                    }
                                    else{
                                          $firstCategoryId = $cats[0];
                                    }

                            $_category = $_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($firstCategoryId);
                            $categorykey = $_category->getUrlKey();
                            $siteurl= $block->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]);      
                            $pro_url=$siteurl.$categorykey."/".$_item->getUrlKey().".html";
                            }
                            else{
                                $pro_url=$block->getProductUrl($_item);
                            }
                     ?>
```