# Get the complete path product url

Tags: frontend, magento-2.2.5, product-urls

I'm using Magento EE 2.2.5

I need to get the product url of a product with its category path.

Presently, I'm using the code

```
$product_url = $product->getUrlInStore();
```

And also tried with

```
$product_url = $product->getProductUrl();
```

I'm getting like: www.domain.com/product_url_key

But I need to get it like: www.domain.com/category_level_1/category_level_2/product_url_key

So is there any default function to get that?

Comment: maybe [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158709/how-to-get-product-url-with-category-key-on-home-page) will help you

Comment: seems it's core error track [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12662), but just try with above link maybe it will solve your issue

Comment: So is it like we have to build the url manually, we dont have any default function for that?

Comment: No, you don't need to write any function just follow [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/158718/55928) answer

Comment: In which page , you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

You can change in configuration for same and after making changes in configuration, please do the re-indexing.

Changes: go to Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engine Optimization -> "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" set to "Yes"

Comment: I have added this and i want this complete product url in email template item listing href