# Magento 2 Get Full Category Path for product

Tags: magento2, category

How to get full category path in Magento 2?

For example

> Home > Women > Dresses > Maxi Dresses

I am developing script for Google Shopping Feed and there is a node product_type which is require product category in above format

[image]

This node should be in below format:

```
<g:product_type><![CDATA[Home > Women > Dresses > Maxi Dresses]]></g:product_type>
```

I have searched on forum but didn't found any solution for Magento 2.

If anyone any idea then please share me.

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-categories-specific-product-magento-2.html This will help you.

Comment: Check this if it can help you to get an idea: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158709/how-to-get-product-url-with-category-key-on-home-page

Comment: Do you want category names path in request url of product ?

Comment: @Aaditya,please check updated answer.

Comment: Hello @akgola I got your concern product_type is optional in  Google Shopping Feed

Comment: I am checking how can we pass data for that

Comment: @Aaditya,many thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public function __construct(
             \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
                \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
                \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager

            ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;

    }
public function yourfunctionname(){
    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    if (!$categoryIds) {
        return null;
    }
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->get($categoryIds[0], $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
    $this->registry->register('current_category',$category);
    $redirectionUrl = $product->getProductUrl();
 }
```

the __construct contain the dependencies injection you needed to load model and yourfunctionname have the code to get url using the current product page category to get category url

Comment: ,this is returning only url of product ,not full path.

Comment: @akgola what you mean by path .You can't get the path of the product page as html is generated from the magento's structure dynamically

Comment: this will generate url like www.example.com/category/product.html

Comment: ,I mean in format Home > Women > Dresses > Maxi Dresses not url format.

Comment: i added new solution @akgola .please check it

Answer (score 0):

[image: sample]

here a image where i put path below add to cart button just adding below code in addtocart.phtml in

```
app/code/vendor_name/extension_Name/view/frontend/templates/product/view/addtocart.phtml
```

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->toHtml(); ?>
```

add this to any phtml file you will get the path you wanted

**hope this helps you**

Comment: one small query i.e what if customer directly redirect from home page to product page?

Comment: @NagarajuKasa i didn't understand your question because it was to get the path(breadcrumbs)