# how to regenrate every product url with category path magento 2

Tags: magento2, catalog, url-rewrite, product-urls

Hey there i have been searching for solution of my issue
i have multiple product slider widget in diffrent cms pages but the url of that prodcucts are

> http://127.0.0.1/kisna/new-prodcut.html

and on category page the url of same product is

> http://127.0.0.1/kisna/first-parent/second-parent/new-prodcut.html

and if i generate sitemap.xml for the products product url is showing without category path i want a permenant solution to regenerate product urls in sitemap and cms pages.
This helps in SEO .
I have tried many solutions including installing and implenting these two modules but this doesnt work

> https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites

> https://github.com/iazel/magento2-regenurl

my issue is similar to

> [How to get product url with category key on home page](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158709/how-to-get-product-url-with-category-key-on-home-page)

Please help me to get out of this issue
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: And also i want to generate product in canonical url with category path.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/341796/generate-product-url-in-cms-page-catalog-search-page-sitemap-canonical-url-wi

Comment: please review this for more information

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/341796/generate-product-url-in-cms-page-catalog-search-page-sitemap-canonical-url-wi

Comment: can you try any solution from here : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/158709/how-to-get-product-url-with-category-key-on-home-page

Comment: can u tell in which files i have to use this code

Comment: and will it work for xml sitemap

Comment: I have tried one solution that is working for catalog search and CMS pages and HTML sitemap 
but in XML sitemap 
old url is generating

Comment: I an asking you, have you try any solution that given on that link and check that working for you or not?

Comment: Please tell me where to use that code?